# When I use appcompat-v7 version 23.0.0 or newer (for toolbars), I can not make a directory on the device memory

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-appcompat

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hoffmanfam.breakerpanel"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk.jar')
compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.2.1.jar')
}
```

Which is the latest numbers available.  I use this for making a directory on the device memory in my MainActivity.  I have stripped all other code except for this in my app.

```
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/BreakerPanel");
    if(!direct.exists())
    {
        if(!direct.mkdir())
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to create directory: BreakerPanel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

If I use SDK version 22 and appcompat-v7:22.0.0 (or anything lower than 23), everything works fine and the directory is created.  However, with version 23, the directory cannot be created.  I get the Toast "failed to create directory: BreakerPanel" every time.  I decided to just make my app run on version 22 since it all works fine, but I published a beta to the Google Play Store using SDK version 23 (I added in-app purchases during this update).  Apparently you can't downgrade from version 23 to version 22 once you publish an APK, even if it's a beta version.  I have stripped all other code away from my app other than the directory creating step above and it will not do it unless I use SDK version 22 or lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specifically ask for permissions in Api 23 onwards.

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

You have not done this and so do not have permission to write to the external storage folder.

This is nothing to do with AppCompat. It is because of your target SDK.